# On which port does CedarDB run on Heroku?

Tags: mysql, symfony, heroku, doctrine-orm, cleardb

I'm trying to deploy online (on Heroku) my Symfony 2 app and I've configured a ClearDB resource.

Now, when I deploy, I receive this error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused.
>   Is the server running on host "eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com"
>   (176.34.224.153) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Now, which is the port I have to use to connect to my ClearDB instance?

Comment: It was a stupid error: I set SYMFONY__DATABASE_DRIVER as pgsql instead of pdo_mysql. Changing the driver solve the issue. In fact, 5432 is the default port of PostgreSQL, not of MySQL (of which the default port is 3306).